# How can I validate and parse phone numbers to extract their country calling code and area code?

Tags: node.js

I am developing an API and would like to validate phone numbers and, if valid, extract their country code and area code without knowing the region ahead of time? Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just discovered https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js and looks promising.

```
'use strict';

const libphonenumberJs = require("libphonenumber-js");

const phoneNumber = libphonenumberJs.parsePhoneNumberFromString('Phone: 8 (800) 555 35 35.', 'RU');

const countryCode = phoneNumber.number.replace(phoneNumber.nationalNumber, '');

console.log(phoneNumber.number, countryCode);

// +78005553535 +7
```

Comment: How to get the country name or iso code?, both US and Canada are +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from scratch, you can follow the following strategy.

You can create a database table, for example you can call it **valid_country_phone_numbers**. And of course in this table you will insert names of different countries and their country codes, without forgetting insert the length of the phone numbers in that country.

And you can have fields like:

```
    country,
    valid_phone_number_length,
    country_code,
```

I don't know the database that you are using otherwise I could have also displayed the logic.

And on the **frontend** you can ask a user to choose his/her country and then enter their phone number.

To determine if the user has entered valid phone number. You can use the information in the database. For example, what you can do is find the **country name** in the **valid_country_phone_numbers** database table. And then compare the country code if necessary and after that compare the phone number length.

But this will be very difficult if you don't know the country of the person. Otherwise you can take advantage of **html 5** `Geolocation` feature. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)
If you want to know something different, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback James. As there are many international formats, I was hopping to use a maintained library to ease the process.

Comment: `libphonenumber-js` appears to be what I am looking for, but open to receiving more feedback as this is my first time validating and parsing international phone numbers.